# Import JSON into Mongo with the _id as the filename of the JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

**PROBLEM:**

I have a huge dump of json files in the format somewhat like this.

```
cat 00329f9608793cdf176032630ebc42ef.json
{
  "engine": {},
  "engine1": "not_found",
  "engine2": "not_found",
  "engine3": "not_found",
  "engine4": "not_found",
  "engine5": "not_found"
}
```

Now i have created a folder with large no of json files of this format.Now i want to import each and every json into a mongo collection i created,when i try to insert the json file the _id is created with random hash,which is not intended behaviour,what i want is take the filename of the JSON and create _id with the filename.

Suppose 00329f9608793cdf176032630ebc42ef.json should be taken and _id should be created like `00329f9608793cdf176032630ebc42ef`

**What I tried:**

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection myCollection --file 00329f9608793cdf176032630ebc42ef.json --jsonArray
```

**What is required?**

Is there any way to handle my case where the filename should be stored as _id and not any random hash.

Answer (score 1):

add following key-value map to the original json file might be a right direction.

```
"_id": {"$oid":"your_filename_here"}
```